# Dynamically create base class or inherited class

Tags: c#

Title may not say what exactly I am trying to do.
I am not sure if this is even possible, but maybe there is a workaround.
The code below is only to try to show what I want to achieve, I know this is wrong. Is it possible to create base class or inherited class at runtime? Or achieve the goal somehow else? I hope you will get the main idea from code. If not, I'll try to explain more.

```
public class BaseClass {
    public int baseNumber {get; set;};
}

public class DerivecClass : BaseClass {
    public int derivedNumber {get; set;};
}

public BaseClass Foo(bool derived) {
    var classInstance;

    if (derived) {
       classInstance = new DerivedClass();
    } else {
       classInstance = new BaseClass();
    }

    classInstance.baseNumber = 1234;

    if (derived) {
        classInstance.derivedNumber = 4321;
    }
    return classInstance;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for the Factory pattern.

Comment: So you want a BaseClass constructor to "return" a DerivedClass?  No, that's not possible.  You should look at the [Factory Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx)

Comment: It might help to explain what exactly you need to use this for? (What do you intend to do with the generated instance) I'd imagine you'd require another if statement or similar on the outside to actually use it

Answer (score 1):

You can't "rebase" a class at runtime (and implicitly all the classes subclass another class or `System.Object` (that is another class :-) )

You can create at runtime new dynamic classes through the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace. You need to use the [TypeBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx) class. This new classes can subclass nearly any class that isn't sealed and that doesn't have a `private`/`internal` constructor (there are some special exceptions)

If you want a simple Factory Pattern, then that is easy:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int baseNumber { get; set; }

    // So that BaseClass can't be created by other code through
    // the new BaseClass()
    protected BaseClass()
    {
    }

    public static BaseClass Create(bool derived)
    {
        BaseClass classInstance;

        if (derived)
        {
            classInstance = new DerivedClass();
        }
        else
        {
            classInstance = new BaseClass();
        }

        classInstance.baseNumber = 1234;

        if (derived)
        {
            ((DerivedClass)classInstance).derivedNumber = 4321;
        }

        return classInstance;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int derivedNumber { get; set; }

    // So that DerivedClass can't be created by other code through
    // the new DerivedClass()
    protected DerivedClass()
    {
    }
}
```

This pattern, nearly exactly as written, is used by [XmlReader.Create(String, XmlReaderSettings)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms162474.aspx)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Who am I to put limits to Icarus? :-)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov xanatos is right, we shouldn't deny him something that may help him. Plus, someone else might come stumbling over the question and the hint makes his day! :)

Comment: I am so sorry. I didn't see that I have forgotten function name AND return statement, and also haven't mentioned anywhere that it was supposed to be a function. I guess you all tought, that it was constructor.... This really got out of hand. I don't even know what to do now as so many answers already. Anyway, I updated the question. Sorry again :/

Comment: @John, thanks for the clarification. However, I think you're still looking at a Factory Pattern. This is a standard _Gang of 4_ pattern so is completely in line with all the good design guidelines you'd care to list.  If you _really_ want you could create a static method in the **derived** class to perform the `if (derived)` check and return the appropriate type.  Usage would then be something like `var instance = DerivedClass.YourStaticMethod(true);` (IMO a factory class would be better to future-proof your code - for example if you were to add another level to the class hierarchy.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! This is something new to me and I am still trying to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create base class or inherited class at runtime?

Not with a constructor, but you could use a static factory method:

```
public static BaseClass Create (bool derived) {
    BaseClass classInstance;

    if (derived) {
       classInstance = new DerivedClass();
    } else {
       classInstance = new BaseClass();
    }

    classInstance.baseNumber = 1234;

    if (derived) {
        ((DerivedClass)classInstance).derivedNumber = 4321;
    }

    return classInstance;
}
```

Note that the code could be simplified somewhat (using initializers, removing casts, etc.) but this is as close to your original example as I could get.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to my Factory Pattern comment, you would have something like the following:

Classes:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int BaseNumber {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClassA()
    {
        BaseNumber = 1234;
    }
}

public class DerivedClassB : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClassB()
    {
        BaseNumber = 4321;
    }
}
```

Factory:

```
public class ClassFactory
{
    // I'd use an Enum parameter rather than a string, but you get the idea
    public static BaseClass GetClass(string classType)
    {
        if classType.Equals("A")
            return new DerivedClassA();
        else
            return new DerivedClassB();
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
 BaseClass class = ClassFactory.GetClass("A");
```